# Using session while sending set of AJAX requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application I make set of AJAX calls at once and that causes sending the same session cookie for each request.
The problem is that rails sets new session cookie in every response and therefore it expects that cookie value in the request after.

I'm looking for **server-side solution** because I don't want to chain those requests (they are time consuming).

Is it possible to change this behavior? And what security risks would come with it?

(I'm using Rails 4.1.0)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user doesn't already have a session cookie then there is nothing you can do.

If you can guarantee that the user already has a session (for example, if you require users to be logged in) then you may be able to do this with a server side session store.

With a server side session store the session cookie just contains an identifier - even if your overlapping ajax requests change values in the session they will not change the session cookie. In general this is better security wise: for example, old sessions can't be replayed after the user has logged out. Rails switched to the cookie store by default for performance reasons: no external data store needs to be accessed (however it does slightly increase the amount of data sent on each request)

Switching to a serverside session store isn't enough though and still leaves you open to race conditions. It is very easy to end up with a sequence along the lines of

- Request A loads session
- Request B loads session
- Request B completes, saves session
- Request A saves session and overwrites the session changes made by B

You need a session store that will attempt to merge any changes it has made with any changes that may have occurred from other requests.

I wrote such a [session store](https://github.com/fcheung/smart_session_store)  some time ago. I haven't updated it for rails 4, since it isn't something i need anymore but you may be able to (or at least find inspiration in it)

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I looked into it and found suitable gem for this. https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store
...
I think there's no reason to concern about the condition you mentioned at the very beginning because session is set after the first request and after that come those AJAX calls (with session_id already defined).

Comment: The session store I linked to was written because active record store (that used to be part of rails) exhibited race conditions the way we were using it. That may have changed, but do check

Comment: Luckily I don't have to worry about it in my project because only one of those requests writes to session. So the problem was really only in the sequence of calls. But you're right other readers should consider this.